# how to solve Fatal error: Class 'Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Mysql4_Setup' not found in includes\src\Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php on line 234

Tags: magento-1.9, setup

[image]

I install SMTP mail extension from magento connect manager..but when I return to my admin page from that window... after that admin page(back-end) and front-end both are not show..and error generate of this type..

**Fatal error:** `Class 'Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Mysql4_Setup'` not found in `D:\NIORN\wamp\www\magentosec\includes\src\Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php` on line 234

So ,you have any answer of this error. Please suggest...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have Compiler turned on. Turn it off every time you install an extension or you might face this kind of issue a lot. When you're done, you can re-compile and turn it back on.

[image]